# How to make this program considered as a recursive rfunciton

Tags: c, recursion

I have created the program that functionally works the way it is supposed to but I have to make it recursive and I was told that function `void expand()` is not considered as a recursive function. Any tips?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max_size 300

int main(){
   char defstr[max_size]="The universe is ever expanding!";
   int num, buff_num;
   printf("Input how much to expand: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   buff_num=num;
   expand(defstr, num, 0, 0);
   return 0;
}

void expand(char str[max_size], int n, int dash, int i){
    if(n>-1){
        if(str[i+1]!='\0'){
          printf("%c",str[i]);
            for(int j=dash; j>0; j--)
            printf("-");
            expand(str, n, dash, i+1);
        }
        else if(str[i+1]=='\0'){
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            printf("\n");
            expand(str, n-1, dash+1, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The program is built to output this type of text depending on the user input of how many dashes.

```
T-h-e- -u-n-i-v-e-r-s-e- -i-s- -e-v-e-r- -e-x-p-a-n-d-i-n-g-!
T--h--e-- --u--n--i--v--e--r--s--e-- --i--s-- --e--v--e--r-- --e--x--p--a--n--d--i--n--g--!
T---h---e--- ---u---n---i---v---e---r---s---e--- ---i---s--- ---e---v---e---r--- ---e---x---p---a---n---d---i---n---g---!
```

Comment: Whoever told you it is not recursive is incorrect.

Comment: That is a recursive function.

Comment: Maybe the function is supposed to print the entire string (with the correct number of dashes) each time.

Comment: He told me " it is more of a "if-else" function" and I should make it a unary recursive function

Comment: See my previous comment. It should probably be something like `void expand(char *str, int num_dashes) { if (num_dashes < 0) return; expand(str, num_dashes - 1); // For loop to print entire string with dashes;}`

Comment: The output of the program is exactly, the output that is required for the program. So the code creates the intended output but it must be a recursive.

Comment: I think you may want to ask some more probing questions to whomever gave you this critique.  What you have is recursive.  A quick Google search for [unary recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) functions makes me question if he truly understands himself. Even the good suggestion from @JohnnyMopp is _binary_ not _unary_ in nature. Regardless of the number of arguments, what you have is recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a recursive function in that it calls itself. However, my guess is that is is supposed to print the entire string with dashes each time.

```
void expand(char *str, int num_dashes)
{
    // End recursion
    if (num_dashes < 0) return;
    
    // Call recursively
    expand(str, num_dashes - 1);
    
    // Print entire string with dashes
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_dashes; j++) {
                fputc('-', stdout);
            }
        }
        fputc(str[i], stdout);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My code seems to work but yours looks like a better implementation of recursion. Ill ask if this is acceptable for the exercise but from my perspective this looks good.